# bitbucket run pipeline for set of service with single click

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm facing an issue when need to deploy +10 services, each time I had to open a bitbucket, and for each service run 3 pipelines manually, which means I'm repeating the deployment steps for all services!!

my question is, is there a way I can do that in a single click? like hey, bitbucket, this is the list of services, do deploy?

I use bitbucket API to do such a thing (write a java script integrated with bitbucket API), but I had to run this locally, I need a way to do it via bitbucket UI

Comment: Are all those services deployed from the same monorepository but different pipelines or do you mean you'd like to orchestrate pipelines across different repos?

Comment: the second option, deploy a list of services with one click (orchestrate pipelines across different repos)